# Many to many relations when scaffolding app

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm wondering how many to many relationships are specified for `phoenix.gen.html` or `phoenix.gen.json` while scaffolding the app. It's common to use `references` to create one-to-many relationships, like below:

```
mix phoenix.gen.model Video videos name:string approved_at:datetime description:text likes:integer views:integer user_id:references:users
```

But how to pass many-to-many fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run

```
mix phoenix.gen.model UserVideo users_videos user_id:references:users video_id:references:videos
```

and then update your schemas

```
alias MyApp.{User, UserVideo}
schema "videos" do
  ...
  many_to_many :users, User, join_through: UserVideo
end

alias MyApp.{Video, UserVideo}
schema "users" do
  ...
  many_to_many :videos, Video, join_through: UserVideo
end
```

Comment: Hmm, I suspected I would have to do something like this. But is this the recommended way? And what about migrations? Do I have to write them from scratch? Sorry I have too many questions -- very new to Phoenix. :|

Comment: @dotslash According to docs https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#many_to_many/3 there is no other option than join_through.
You can choose between generating model and `join_through: UserVideo` or just migration and `join_through: "users_videos"`.
I believe there is no recommended way, you should choose option that fits to your needs.

Comment: Okay, thanks. This does answer my question, but I'm still very confused about how migrations will be handled. Time to dive deeper!

Comment: @dotslash Personally I don't use generators and write everything myself from scratch, but they should provide you some basics to start with (as far I remember some migrations too).